# How do I write a program that calculates string length and number of times a white space appears in the string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I'm not very good at programming and I've been asked to make a program that uses two functions. The first calculates the length of the string in a array. The second counts the white spaces in that same string. Here is what I have, I know it's not very good.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[]={"To be or not to be – that is the question: Whether 'tis noble in the          mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, or to take arms against a sea of     troubles and, by opposing, end them. To die, to sleep"};

void (char stringLength( char string[ ])
{
    int x = 0;

    while(string+x)
        x++;

    return x;
}

void space ( int numSpace(char string[])) {

    int x;
    numSpace = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++) {
        if(x[string] == ' ') {
            (numSpace)++;

            return numSpace;
        }
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    printf("string : %s\n", x);
    printf("total number of blank spaces : %d\n", numSpace);

    return 0;
}
```

The char string [] is supposed to be: To be or not to be – that is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, or to take arms against a sea of troubles and, by opposing, end them. To die, to sleep" For some reason when I posted my code it all stayed on one line.  I don't know how to fix that problem either. I"m really over my head here.

Comment: It would help if you posted compilable code; the definition of `stringLength` has a stray `(` before the function name, and the function `space` appears to take a pointer to a function as an argument (if it compiles at all; I have reservations about that), which is unlikely to be what you had in mind.  Inside `stringLength`, you'd do better with the `string[x]` notation — you're missing a `*` and `( )` from `*(string + x)` in the condition of the loop. Inside what is probably supposed to be `NumSpace`, the `x[string]` notation is valid but very aconventional way of writing `string[x]`.

Comment: This resembles a working program that has been intentionally scrambled a bit. Did you write this code?

Comment: "the function space appears to take a pointer to a function as an argument" -- not to me. Rather, the declaration of the local variable numspace got wedged into the function header for some reason. Again, it resembles something scrambled: `int space (char string[]) { int numspace;`

Comment: @JimBalter: With a changed return type — for my convenience — this function compiles: `int space ( int numSpace(char string[])) { return numSpace("a b c"); }`, justifying my comment about 'pointer to function' and discounting my 'if it compiles at all'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure it does but so what? My answer is pretty obviously closer to the intent. It makes no sense to set a function pointer (called numSpace) to 0 and then increment it in a loop, now does it? But it makes perfect sense if it's an int variable.

Comment: why declaring `void` functions if they do return some values? I agrre with @JimBalter this is not the asker's own code

Comment: @JimBalter: Of course; my initial comment also said that it was unlikely to be what was intended...someone having this much difficulty writing `strlen()` isn't deliberately writing code that takes a pointer to a function. But it is, curiously enough, a valid start to a function, even if the body is not all valid (you can't return a value from a function with return type `void`, etc).  And you know all that, so we're probably violently agreeing.

Comment: @chouaib I suspect it's the OP's code but was copied from something else with no understanding.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "so we're probably violently agreeing" -- you're right; I overlooked your "unlikely" comment -- I apologize.

Comment: "For some reason when I posted my code it all stayed on one line. I don't know how to fix that problem either. " -- Actually, your code is properly indented, which is somewhat unusual for an SO neophyte. (Or maybe someone quickly fixed it for you -- for some bizarre reason SO doesn't record edits done shortly after a question is posted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. with

```
 gcc -Wall -g yourcode.c -o yourbin
```

(at least on Linux)

Your declaration `void (char stringLength( char string[ ])` is non-sense. The first parenthesis is wrong. A result cannot be both `void` and `char`. A string length can be bigger than 255 (often, the maximal value of a `char` i.e. `CHAR_MAX` from `<limits.h>` header).

```
unsigned stringLength(char string[ ]) {
 unsigned x = 0;
 while(string[x] != '\0')
    x++;
 return x;
}
```

a string length is an unsigned i.e. non-negative number (actually it is a `size_t`, but let's pretend it is `unsigned`).

Your test `while(string+x)` is wrong (will have an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). [Pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm) is [nearly] always non-null when the pointer is non-null and the offset non-negative (actually, it will overflow and wrap to 0, but before that you'll get a [segmentation violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)). You want to access the memory `string[x]`

Your `for(x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++)` loop is extremely inefficient, you are computing `strlen(string)` at every loop (so the complexity of your loop is *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* instead of *O(N)*). You could compute `strlen(string)` before, e.g. `size_t l = strlen(string); for (x=0; x<l; x++)` or more wisely notice that you should stop at the terminating zero byte:  `for(x = 0; string[x]!='\0'; x++)`

At last **learn how to use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb yourbin` on Linux) and run your program step by step to understand what is happening.

Also, take several hours to read good tutorial material on C programming. Practice a lot. It will become fun.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, this looks like someone took a working program and intentionally scrambled it. It doesn't take much to turn it back into a working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[]={"To be or not to be – that is the question: Whether 'tis noble in the          mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, or to take arms against a sea of     troubles and, by opposing, end them. To die, to sleep"};

int stringLength( char string[ ])
{
    int x = 0;

    while(string[x])
        x++;

    return x;
}

int space (char string[])
{
    int numSpace;
    int x;
    numSpace = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++) { // expensive to call strlen on each iteration
        if(x[string] == ' ') { // legal but unusual; string[x] is more sensible
            (numSpace)++;
        }
    }

    return numSpace;

}

int main(void)
{
    printf("string : %s\n", string);
    printf("length of string: %d\n", stringLength(string));
    printf("total number of blank spaces : %d\n", space(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why    `char str[] = {"sdsddfsc"};`? when u can just use `char str[] = "sddccw";`

Comment: @chouaib Uh, because that's the way it is in the OP's code, to which I made minimal changes.